# Maps for other countries in Amazon Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am using Amazon Quicksight as our enterprise BI application within the organization. And now I want to use the spatial data to visualize some maps over Europe and Asia. I see an option to include the US in the maps but I don't see an option to do the same for anything other than the US.

Is this a limitation from the Quicksight team that we can only use maps for the US and no other countries at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. Currently only the US is supported for the Filled map visualization option. You can find this documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/geospatial-charts.html
You can work around that using the latitude and longitude coordinates is the visualization called Points on map. You will need to provide the name of the place as an attribute, latitude and longitude.

You can find the list of countries coordinates [here](https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, filled maps are supported at a country level worldwide now.  Point maps support down to City level worldwide too (need to add it to a Hierarchy along with the Country field in the data prep screen).  Both of these were added in ~July 2021.

[country level filled map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxqFy.png)

[city level point map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4hWY.png)]