# Does quicksite allow adding geospatial data of any other country besides the US?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I thought having longitude and latitude coordinates where enough to plot a map but that seems not the case. I have read about hierarchies but I cannot seem to see any other country in the countries option.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer in this post:
[Maps for other countries in Amazon Quicksight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259316/maps-for-other-countries-in-amazon-quicksight/66369593#66369593).
So actually you will be able to draw a map by only two attributes of the coordinates using the `Points on map` visualization. to provide the place name when hovering on it, you would add a third attribute and place it on the color field well of the visualization.

[image]